# Recursive generator on list of lists

Tags: python, recursion, generator

I have 2 demotion list that looks like that:

```
[[1,2,3,],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]]
```

I'm trying to write a generator that yield the sum of a 'path'.

A 'path' starts from left-top corner and goes only on x+1 and y+1 until it's get to it's last element(the right bottom).

For example, a valid path is `1=>2=>5=>6=>9 (sum=23)`.

None-valid path could be `1=>2=>5=>**4**=>`...

So far I have this code:

```
my_list = [[0, 2, 5], [1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1]]   
def gen(x, y, _sum):
    if x + 1 <= len(my_list):
        for i1 in gen(x + 1, y, _sum + my_list[y][x]):
            yield _sum
    if y + 1 <= len(my_list):
        for i2 in gen(x, y + 1, _sum + my_list[y][x]):
            yield _sum
    yield _sum + my_list[y][x]


g = gen(0, 0, 0)
total = 0
for elm in g:
    total += elm

print total
```

I get the error:

```
  for i2 in gen(x, y+1, _sum+my_list[y][x]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: So whats the problem ?

Comment: Presumably you wanted to find the *maximum* path through the matrix. If so, brute-force generating all possible paths is not the best way of solving this problem. Rather, solve the problem in terms of a smaller matrix; the maximum sum of a given cell is the maximum of the same value of the cell above and to the left, plus the current value.

Comment: Since you already know the maximum path value for the *top left* cell of the matrix, the maximum path value can easily be calculated for every other cell too, giving you the maximum path value for the whole matrix at the end. All it takes is a NxM loop over the matrix.

Comment: @MartijnPieters could you explain it with code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error is a simple off-by-one error.*

I think what you wanted here is `x <= len(my_list)` or, equivalently, `x+1 < len(my_list)`; you've doubled-up the +1-ness, causing you to run past the end of the list.

Consider a concrete case:

- `len(my_list)` is 3. `x` is `2`. So, `x+1 <= len(my_list)` is `3 <= 3`, which is true. So you call yourself recursively with `gen(3, …)`.
- In that recursive call, `4 <= 3` is false, so, depending on the value of `y`, you call either:

  - `gen(x, y + 1, _sum + my_list[y][3])`, or
  - `_sum + my_list[y][3]`
  - … either of which will raise an `IndexError`.

Obviously you need to fix the same problem with `y` as with `x`.

You can see it running without errors [here](http://repl.it/52Z).

---

Of course it doesn't actually print out the right result, because there are other problems in your code. Off the top of my head:

- `total = + elm` replaces whatever's in `total` with the value of `elm`. You probably wanted `+=`, not `= +` here.
- Yielding `_sum` over and over and ignoring the values yielded by the recursive generators can't possibly be doing any good. Maybe you wanted to yield `i1` and `i2` instead?

I can't guarantee that those are the only problems in your code, just that they are problems.

---

<sub>* I'm assuming here that this is a silly bug, not a fundamental error—you clearly know that indexes are 0-based, since you called the function with `gen(0, 0, 0)` rather than `gen(1, 1, 0)`.</sub>

Comment: sorry but this is not the case, you can look on the error I posted, its not this line(I tried your solution anyway.. didn't work)

Comment: Actually I added the x+1 after i got the error just to check it out :/

Comment: It's the same error; it's just happening in the `i2` loop rather than the final `yield`. If you fix it, the error does go away.

Comment: @OrDuan: More importantly, it _does_ make the error go away. I added a link to an online Python interpreter to prove it, if you don't buy the explanation.

Comment: Thanks! my problem was that i yielded the _sum and not the i's.

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to brute-force all permissible paths through an N x M matrix, then simply generate all permutations of N - 1 moves to the right plus M - 1 moves down, then use those moves to sum the values along the path:

```
from itertools import permutations

def gen_path_sum(matrix):
    N, M = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    for path in permutations([(1, 0)] * (N - 1) + [(0, 1)] * (M - 1)):
        sum = matrix[0][0]
        x = y = 0
        for dx, dy in path:
            x += dx; y += dy
            sum += matrix[x][y]
        yield sum
```

This'll produce (N + M)! paths; there are 720 such paths for a 3 by 3 matrix.

However, if you are trying to find the *maximum* path through the matrix, you are going about it the inefficient way.

You can instead calculate the maximum path for any cell in the matrix; it is simply the greatest of the maximum path values of the cell above and to the left, plus value of the current cell. So for the cell in the top left (with no cells above or to the right), the maximum path value is the value of the cell.

You can calculate all those values with a N X M loop:

```
def max_path_value(matrix):
    totals = [row[:] for row in matrix]
    for x, row in enumerate(totals):
        for y, cell in enumerate(row):
            totals[x][y] += max(
                totals[x - 1][y] if x else 0,
                totals[x][y - 1] if y else 0
            )
    return totals[-1][-1]
```

This only takes N X M steps, or 9 steps in total for your 3 by 3 matrix. That's a factor of 80 better than the brute-force approach.

The contrast only increases as your matrix sizes increase; a 10x10 matrix, brute forced, requires examining 2432902008176640000 paths (== 20!), or you can just calculate the maximum path with 100 steps instead.